# How to plot a system of recurrence equations

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, difference-equations

I have the following code working well ... but I would then like to plot M[k] and L[k] on the same axes with k along the horizontal and M[k] and L[k] values along the vertical. The graph I'm looking to automatically generate from the code is below. I've tried various constructs of DiscretePlot and ListPlot but to no avail ... I'd appreciate suggestions!!

```
Clear[a, b, k, M, L, M0, L0, NN]
NN = 25; a = 2/10; b = 1/10; M0 = 30; L0 = 50;
N[TableForm[
  MapThread[
   Prepend, {RecurrenceTable[{M[k + 1] == (1 - a)*M[k] + a*L[k], 
      L[k + 1] == (1 - b)*L[k] + b*M[k], M[0] == M0, L[0] == L0}, {M, 
      L}, {k, 0, NN}], Range[0, NN]}], 
  TableHeadings -> {{}, {"k", "M[k]", "L[k]"}}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Straightforward method:

```
With[{NN = 25, a = 2/10, b = 1/10, M0 = 30, L0 = 50},
     ListLinePlot[Transpose[RecurrenceTable[{M[k + 1] == (1 - a) M[k] + a L[k], 
                                             L[k + 1] == (1 - b) L[k] + b M[k],
                                             M[0] == M0, L[0] == L0},
                                            {M, L}, {k, 0, NN}]],
                  DataRange -> {0, NN}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Slick method:

```
With[{NN = 25, a = 2/10, b = 1/10, M0 = 30, L0 = 50},
     ListLinePlot[Transpose[NestList[{{1 - a, a}, {b, 1 - b}}.# &, {M0, L0}, NN]], 
                  DataRange -> {0, NN}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Even slicker method:

```
With[{NN = 25, a = 2/10, b = 1/10, M0 = 30, L0 = 50},
     DiscretePlot[MatrixPower[{{1 - a, a}, {b, 1 - b}}, k, {M0, L0}] // Evaluate,
                  {k, 0, NN}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True,
                  PlotRange -> All]]
```

All three versions produce the following figure:

[image: figure]

Comment: wonderfully creative, J. M. ... can DiscretePlot also be used in some way to show the points along the curve?

Comment: Sure, just add the option setting `PlotMarkers -> {"Point", Medium}` to `DiscretePlot[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, JM, very clever coding!!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {
   M[k + 1] == (1 - a)*M[k] + a*L[k],
   L[k + 1] == (1 - b)*L[k] + b*M[k],
   M[0] == M0, L[0] == L0};
```

[`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) provides the exact solution to the recurrence equations

```
sol = RSolve[eqns, {L, M}, k][[1]]

{* {L -> Function[{k}, (a L0 + (1 - a - b)^k b L0 + b M0 - (1 - a - b)^k b M0)/(
   a + b)], M -> 
  Function[{k}, -((-a L0 + a (1 - a - b)^k L0 - a (1 - a - b)^k M0 - b M0)/(
    a + b))]} *}
```

Verifying,

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

{* {True, True, True, True} *}
```

For your specific parameters,

```
solEx[k_] = {L[k], M[k]} /. sol /.
   {a -> 2/10, b -> 1/10, M0 -> 30, L0 -> 50} // Simplify

{* {1/3 10^(1 - k) (2 7^k + 13 10^k), 1/3 10^(1 - k) (-4 7^k + 13 10^k)} *}
```

The functions share a common limit

```
lim = Limit[solEx[k], k -> Infinity]

(* {130/3, 130/3} *)
```

Plotting

```
With[{NN = 25},
 Plot[Evaluate@solEx[k], {k, 0, NN},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"L", "M"}, {0.5, 0.3}],
  Prolog -> {Gray, Dashed,
    Line[{{0, lim[[1]]}, {NN, lim[[1]]}}]}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If `RSolve` is unable to solve:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

NN = 25; a = 2/10; b = 1/10; M0 = 30; L0 = 50;
rt = RecurrenceTable[{M[k + 1] == (1 - a)*M[k] + a*L[k], 
    L[k + 1] == (1 - b)*L[k] + b*M[k], M[0] == M0, L[0] == L0}, {M, L}, {k, 0,
     NN}];

M[k_Integer] := rt[[k + 1, 1]] /; 0 <= k <= NN

L[k_Integer] := rt[[k + 1, 2]] /; 0 <= k <= NN

DiscretePlot[{L[k], M[k]}, {k, 0, NN},
 PlotRange -> All, Filling -> None,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.5, 0.3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bob: This is very nice and clever. The convergence line is a nice feature; when RSolve can't solve a system, I resort to the RecurrenceTable. How would sol = work when storing values from a recurrence table?

Comment: `sol[k_] := table[[k]]`

Comment: but, what if I started with the RecurrenceTable instead of RSolve, as RSolve doesn't always produce a solution?

Comment: Bob: Many thanks for the edit -- very helpful and I've learned much. Thanks for sharing your talents.

Comment: Corrected index in definitions of `L[k]` and `M[k]`

Comment: that clears up the "Part, depth, unequal length" error I was getting!!